# Relevance Scores and Sorting with ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I am trying to combine both relevance score and sorting by another field and am not sure how to go about it.

My documents have a number of text fields I want to search for a term against.  The term may appear in a variety of fields in the document.

I am using the following to do that basic filter:

```
  "query_string": {
    "query": "Burger",
    "default_field": "*"
  }
}
```

I also have a field **popularityScore** that measures the popularity of a document.  I tried sorting by that:

```
  "query": {
    "query_string": {
      "query": "Burger",
      "default_field": "*"
    }
  },
  "sort": [
    {
      "popularityScore": {
        "order": "desc"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

By doing that the relevance of the query becomes irrelevant and without it a small deviation in relevance can cause very popular documents to show up lower.  Is there a way I can either combine popularityScore and relevance OR cap one (e.g. only return relevance > x and then sort those)?

Comment: Can you elaborate how you want to combine popularityScore  and relevance. Score are relative to documents returned and these are not absolute values so  comparing them with static value doesn't make sense

Comment: The popularityScore itself is also a relative value (pre-computed) so I think some type of weighted multiplier would work.  That said, I'm open to other approaches, what I am trying to avoid is long tails of either VERY high relevance score with very low popularity score (or the opposite).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use field [function_score](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-function-score-query.html) and [field_value_factor](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-function-score-query.html#function-field-value-factor)

**Query**

```
{
  "query": {
    "function_score": {
      "query": {
        "query_string": {
          "query": "Burger",
          "default_field": "*"
        }
      },
      "functions": [
        {
          "field_value_factor": {
            "field": "popularityScore",
            "factor": 1.2,
            "modifier": "sqrt",
            "missing": 1
          }
        }
      ],
      "boost_mode": "sum"
    }
  }
}
```

**Result**

```
"hits" : [
      {
        "_index" : "index35",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "gLyT6XsBQ6SrO4ATYGUQ",
        "_score" : 3.9282646,
        "_source" : {
          "title" : "Burger",
          "popularityScore" : 12
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "index35",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "fryS6XsBQ6SrO4AT_WXV",
        "_score" : 3.5976331,
        "_source" : {
          "title" : "Burger",
          "popularityScore" : 10
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "index35",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "f7yT6XsBQ6SrO4ATC2WI",
        "_score" : 3.231918,
        "_source" : {
          "title" : "Burger",
          "popularityScore" : 8
        }
      }
    ]
```

> The field_value_factor function allows you to use a field from a document to influence the score.

function_score = sqrt(1.2 * doc['popularityScore'].value)"

document_score = function_score + query_score.

You can choose "modifier" based on how much you want to affect the query score. You will find multiple options for this in [field_value_factor](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-function-score-query.html#function-field-value-factor) documentation.